# Ошибка при выборке из базы

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Где здесь ошибка

```
 $a = mysql_query('SELECT id, text, avatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname FROM massage massage join datacenter datacenter on datacenter.id = massage.id_finish WHERE id_start = $id');

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
  {
 echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: SELECT ..., datacenter.name, datacenter.surname FROM

Comment: Куда вставить?

Вот так

    "SELECT id, text, avatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname FROM massage massage join datacenter datacenter on datacenter.id = massage.id_finish WHERE id_start = $id");

пишет 

>Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: Значит, ты пишешь что-то типа
     
    $str = 'SELECT * FROM table';
    while(mysql_fetch_array($str)){....}

Т.е. забыл сделать запрос :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо посмотреть приходят ли вообще эти значения, для этого зделай

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select){print_r($row);}
```

И дальше уже смотри что у тебя под каким индексом массива

Вообще непонятно зачем сдесь использовать fetch_array, используй fetch_assoc и никаких проблем не будет, т.е.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
     echo $row['surname'];
     echo $row['name'];
     echo $row['любое другое значение указанное в строке запроса'];
}
```

И, на всякий случай, добавь уточнение в запросе - datacenter.name, datacenter.surname вместо name И surname соответственно